# Iphone lock screen application

Tags: iphone, lockscreen

friends I am new to iphone development, I have mostly worked with Android, now I have to develop a small clock for Iphone which should be shown on lock screen like following app

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/weather-lock-screen-free/id433369569?mt=8

just a start idea how can i place an app at iphone lock screen since i have already created the (analog ) clock, thanks for your help

Faisal

Comment: You have to? I hope you didn't sell this concept to a client/boss...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This app doesn't actually set the background of the lock screen. It asks the user to save an image, then the user has to set the image as the background for the lock screen manually.

There is no API to do what you want.